# Recover whole resource from compiled executable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, resources, embedded-resource

We are using resource files to localize our native C++ app. Unfortunately, the rc file has been lost. I was asked to recover this resource file, but we only have compiled binaries containing this resources. Is there any way I can extract the resource from compiled dll so I can add this rc file in our solution for future extensions. I tried exporting it from Resource Hacker but after adding this exported rc file in vcxproj it didn't build at all. Gave many errors. My guess is that it didn't generate VS-C++ compatible rc file. Maybe there's a simpler approach?

Comment: The simpler approach is to recover the RC file from your source control system. Clearly that is not an option. Thank your lucky stars that *most* of the resource data can be recovered using, e.g., Resource Hacker. Repackaging it into an RC file cannot be that hard. It is significantly less effort than recreating the resources from scratch.

Comment: The resource is huge, with lot's of dependencies on other header files and resource files. StringTable contains thousands of entries. Fixing those issues everywhere would take an eternity, and I don't have so much time unfortunately. :( Yes, recovering from source control is not an option here, as we have bought the product from another company and don't have access to old SC

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate. RC files are not linked into the executable; individual resources are. There is no way to reconstruct a complete hierarchy of resource files from the executable, that information just doesn't exist. Constants #defined in header files won't be there either, as they will have been replaced by the resource compiler's text substitution. The strings can still be recovered, and placed into a new resource file. You might find something that semi-automates this, but I doubt it will be very good. It certainly cannot be complete.

Comment: Well, I'm in trouble I gues :)